# how to make player change color when hit by object...all in 2D game using Csharp. Object is falling from Y axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, 2d, hit

Ok i know im so new to code its insane but i have made some progress in my books with my little game..yes it took me a month to figure out to move a character back and forth using arrow key but i did it nonetheless..So now im really stuck
how do i make my player change color (for 3  seconds) when hit from an object from above.

its 2D Csharp unity...object is falling from Y axis and my player is X axis...cause if i can do that ...then over time i can apply animation on the player when an object hits it.

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class leafeffects : MonoBehaviour {



  
  
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
  {
   if (col.gameObject.name == "leaf")
   {
   ChangeGameObject(Color.blue);

   else;

    GameObject.bucket(Color.white);

  }
 }
}

Comment: that was my Code i was trying to do...

Comment: @Titanseed please mark the answer as correct, or write down what you did to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script i quickly cooked up for you.
You should do more research, read tutorials, and watch more tutorials.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class changeColorOnHit : MonoBehaviour {
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    void Start(){
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){//whenever we hit something
        sr.color = new Color(2,0,0);//set this object's red color to 200 percent
    }

    void Update(){
        //linear interpolation brings two values closer together proportional to a given third value(time)
        sr.color = Color.Lerp (sr.color,Color.white,Time.deltaTime/1.5f);//slowly linear interpolate. takes about 3 seconds to return to white
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much...i do the best i can...working 2 jobs and i try to watch and read books. I think i have put in 44 hours of youtube tutorials haha..